# Snackbar outside of main activity

Tags: android, webview, android-snackbar

I can display the snackbar from main activty class But I don't know why I can't display outside main activity?
Here's what works fine in main activity

```
Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Test Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

First time I put it in an alternative class there was an error with `findViewById`,so I changed it to this

```
Snackbar.make(view.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Test Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And now there is no error that android studio shows But when I run the app and execute this class this is the error I face with in the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:136)
at com.domain.app.MyWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(MainActivity.java:85)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:274)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:376)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
t com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This error(**which refers to Snackbar**) is highlighted(the link **MainActivity.java:85** is blue):

> com.domain.app.MyWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(MainActivity.java:85)

I also should add that class:

```
class MyWebViewClient extends  WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        String TAG = "Testing: ";
        if (url.endsWith(".mp3")||url.endsWith(".zip")) {
            Log.i(TAG, "download: " + url);
            Snackbar.make(view.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Test Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new DownloadTask().execute(url);
            return true;
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
}
```

As you see the class above is for downloading specific files from a webview and I set the webview client of my webview to this class.The error shows when I want to use this class(download sth) And as you see the error refers to the snackbar.
So I wanted to know **how to use snackbar outside of main activity?**
Thanks for putting your time on this question :)

Comment: `view.findViewById(android.R.id.content)` is going to return null, because that content `View` is not inside the `WebView`. Try it with just `view`.

Comment: @Mike M Thank you; I could guess the problem is a simple mistake that's because I'm a web developer and not a pro at android.Can you suggest me a book or video tutorial or anything that I can learn the bases of android and don't face problems like this in future?

Comment: Not really. I mean, I've not actually read any books, or watched any video tutorials, or anything. I've just picked things up from the documentation, source code, Stack Overflow, etc. I do know of a book authored by a [frequent, well-respected contributor to SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), but I've not read it.

Comment: @Mike M What should I pass instead of `view` generally(in every class)?Cause now I have the same problem in another class that does not have view variable.Sorry I'm asking too much, If you send a general answer to this question I'll accept and vote that.Just tell me what should I pass instead of `view` generally?thanks.